# Window by time attribute and push to stream

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

We have an input stream where events have a time attribute (not the processing time or the event time) by which they have to be put in groups of 1 minute and pushed into a stream(kinesis/kafka sink) when the minute arrives. We thought we could do this using windows. I have these doubts:

1. If we key by the date-time value till the minute, will the key values use up memory? I mean after the minute is passed is there a necessity to delete keys? Or are they abstract and dont actually use up space?
2. Since I have to push events to a sink at the end of processing, how do we handle the reduce / agg functions?

<strike>3. In a situation where the flink application was down, when we bring it back up, how to trigger the windows that should have been triggered by then?</strike> Got the answer for this: the timers are checkpointed and are fired on 
 the following startup.

4. Are we completely missing the point and is there a better way to do this?

EDIT: Adding context: We have a requirement to retry events based on certain business logic(internal validations). Since the operator that we are using (async IO) does not support retires and the only option left is to use Futures by writing custom code, we decided to send this back to the input stream of the application. The time at which the events should be retried depends on business logic again (calculated at runtime). So to accomplish this, we thought we could collect the events according to the date-time value upto the minute of the calculated value and push them into the stream exactly when the time arrives.

Comment: I will be referring to Java APIs but I hope you get the idea. May be you can use the time field from your message and set it as message timestamp using constructor https://kafka.apache.org/0102/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/ProducerRecord.html#ProducerRecord(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Integer,%20java.lang.Long,%20K,%20V). Then at consumer side, you need to read data based on message timestamp. Basically you need to seek to offset for the time and read till next minute. Hints - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55095004/reading-messages-for-specific-timestamp-in-kafka

Comment: I suspect you are doing some aggregations on these minute windows. Could you please update your question accordingly?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by a time attribute that is not the event time?

Comment: @ArvidHeise, I've added some context. Please let me know in case you need more info

Comment: @DavidAnderson, The time attribute is calculated during runtime. Ive added some context. Please let me know incase you need more info.